# Counting number of conversation "exchanges" between two parties

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say you have the following schema:

- `conversations` - `id`
- `messages` - `id`, `content`, `author_id`, `conversation_id`, `created_at`
- `users` - `id` (this is the table that `author_id` is referencing)

And an "exchange" is when a user sends a message and receives a reply, regardless of the number of messages. Here are some examples of some exchanges:

A single exchange:

- user1 "hi"
- user2 "hi"

Another single exchange (because user2 did not respond after user1's 2nd message):

- user1 "hi"
- user2 "hi"
- user2 "how are you?"
- user1 "good"

Two exchanges:

- user1 "hi"
- user2 "hi"
- user1 "how are you?"
- user2 "good"

Also two exchanges:

- user1 "hi"
- user1 "what's your name?"
- user2 "bob, yours?"
- user1 "john"
- user1 "isn't this weather crazy?"
- user1 "we may have to seek shelter"
- user2 "yeah"
- user2 "scary"

I'm looking to count the number of exchanges per conversation.

I don't need the exact SQL (but won't complain if you provide!), just some direction on how this could be accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

You could approach this with `LAG()` and a cumulative `SUM()`. When the author of the current message is different than the author of the last one, a new half of an exchange starts:

```
SELECT 
    conversation_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN author_id = last_author_id THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) / 2 exchanges
FROM (
    SELECT 
        conversation_id,
        author_id,
        LAG(author_id) OVER(PARTITION BY conversation_id ORDER BY created_at) last_author_id
    FROM messages
) x
GROUP BY conversation_id
```

**[Demo on DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gcfDGyDx9SzSd5r76Fpxfy/0)**:

Sample data:

```
| id  | content                     | author_id | conversation_id | created_at               |
| --- | --------------------------- | --------- | --------------- | ------------------------ |
| 1   | hi                          | 1         | 1               | 2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z |
| 2   | hi                          | 2         | 1               | 2019-01-01T00:00:01.000Z |
| 3   | hi                          | 1         | 2               | 2019-01-02T00:00:00.000Z |
| 4   | hi                          | 2         | 2               | 2019-01-02T00:00:01.000Z |
| 5   | how are you?                | 2         | 2               | 2019-01-02T00:00:02.000Z |
| 6   | good                        | 1         | 2               | 2019-01-02T00:00:03.000Z |
| 7   | hi                          | 1         | 3               | 2019-01-03T00:00:00.000Z |
| 8   | hi                          | 2         | 3               | 2019-01-03T00:00:01.000Z |
| 9   | how are you?                | 1         | 3               | 2019-01-03T00:00:02.000Z |
| 10  | good                        | 2         | 3               | 2019-01-03T00:00:03.000Z |
| 11  | hi                          | 1         | 4               | 2019-01-02T00:00:00.000Z |
| 12  | what is your name?          | 1         | 4               | 2019-01-02T00:00:01.000Z |
| 13  | bob, yours?                 | 2         | 4               | 2019-01-02T00:00:02.000Z |
| 14  | john                        | 1         | 4               | 2019-01-02T00:00:03.000Z |
| 15  | isn't this weather crazy?   | 1         | 4               | 2019-01-02T00:00:04.000Z |
| 16  | we may have to seek shelter | 1         | 4               | 2019-01-02T00:00:05.000Z |
| 17  | yeah                        | 2         | 4               | 2019-01-02T00:00:06.000Z |
| 18  | scary                       | 2         | 4               | 2019-01-02T00:00:07.000Z |
```

Results:

```
| conversation_id | exchanges |
| --------------- | --------- |
| 1               | 1         |
| 2               | 1         |
| 3               | 2         |
| 4               | 2         |
```